# Convert a string column to timestamp when read into spark

Tags: apache-spark, timestamp, databricks

I'm trying to read a csv file into spark with databricks, but my time column is in string format, my time column entry is like: **2019-08-01 23:59:05-07:00**, I want to convert it into timestamp type, here's what I tried:

```
df = (spark.read      
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .csv(path_to_file)
  .withColumn("observed", unix_timestamp("dt", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSZ")
  .cast("double")
  .cast("timestamp"))
)
```

But I got error message: `` cannot resolve '`dt`' given input columns ``, I'm guessing I didn't get the **"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSZ"** format right?

Comment: It is complaining that the dataset doesn't have a column named `dt`. Use something like `printSchema` to confirm that the CSV file is read correctly.

Comment: @HristoIliev I though "observed" is my column name and "dt" is the new name.

Comment: The first argument to `withColumn` is the name of the new column, the second argument is the column expression.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your csv looks like this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2019-08-01 23:59:05-07:00',)], ['dt'])
df.show()

+--------------------+
|                  dt|
+--------------------+
|2019-08-01 23:59:...|
+--------------------+
```

You can simply parse the timestamp with a `to_timestamp` function

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp

df.withColumn('observed', to_timestamp('dt', "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX")).show()
+--------------------+-------------------+
|                  dt|           observed|
+--------------------+-------------------+
|2019-08-01 23:59:...|2019-08-02 08:59:05|
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

So, as @HristoIliev mentioned, the reason behind `` cannot resolve '`dt`' `` is that 'dt' is supposed to be name of the column already in your dataframe, and 'observed' is supposed to be the name of a new column. If you adjust the names thought it still won't work, because there is format mismatch: `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSZ` won't parse 2019-08-01 23:59:05-07:00, but `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX"` will.